# How to split a string in python based on dots, ignoring decimal values?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

> s = 'This .is sparta 1.2 version. Please check.'

I want to split it based on dots, while ignoring decimal figures.
So, Required Output :

> ['This ','is sparta 1.2 version','Please check']

I tried following:

```
    re.split(r'\.(?!([\d+\.\d+]))',s)
```

The output I am getting is:

> ['This ', None, 'is sparta 1.2 version', '', ' Please check', None, '']

Why am I getting None and empty strings here? I just want the split strings, ie.

> ['This ','is sparta 1.2 version','Please check']

Please suggest the rectification here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try splitting on

```
(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)
```

It makes sure the dot isn't preceded, nor followed, by a digit.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iA0xQ2/1).

Comment: Great.  It works. You learn and grow with every regex. Thanks for sharing. @ClasG

Comment: It will not work if a sentence ends with a decimal number: ```s = 'This .is sparta 1.2. version. Please check.'```

Answer (score 2):

```py
re.split(r'(?<=\D)\.(?=.)|(?<=\d)\.(?=\D)', item)
```

This will split the string *item* by dot and will ignore the decimal points.

Find cheatsheet for regular expression in this link:
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/

Comment: It will work even if a sentence ends with a decimal number: ```s = 'This .is sparta 1.2. version. Please check.'```. But the last dot will remains.

Comment: This should be the correct answer instead of the top voted reply. This answer will work on the following text, where the top-voted answer failed: "this is my para. 3.14 is a decimal. 42. is not a decimal.2 out of 3 people forgot about spacing."

Answer (score 0):

Since almost have what you want, you could parse the current output to remove Nones and empty strings.

This can be done in one line using list comprehension:

```
FilteredList = [ itm for itm in UnfilteredList if itm is not None and len(itm)>0]
```

Comment: Besides being not exactly an elegant approach, the comprehension can be simplified to *[item for item in UnfilteredList if item]*.